# How to fetch only few fields from all the MongoDB records

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB work and I need help in the following.

I have a collection named `student` in MongoDB. And I have the following data in it.

```
{'_id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'dt_joined': '2010'}
{'_id': 2, 'name': 'B', 'dt_joined': '2011'}
{'_id': 3, 'name': 'C', 'dt_joined': '2009'}
{'_id': 4, 'name': 'D', 'dt_joined': '2010'}
{'_id': 5, 'name': 'E', 'dt_joined': '2008'}
```

From the above collection, I want to retrieve (_id, dt_joined) from all the records. That means, I'm expecting the following result.

```
{'_id': 1, 'dt_joined': '2010'}
{'_id': 2, 'dt_joined': '2011'}
{'_id': 3, 'dt_joined': '2009'}
{'_id': 4, 'dt_joined': '2010'}
{'_id': 5, 'dt_joined': '2008'}
```

Is it possible with the MongoDB find command?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
db.student.find({}, {_id:1, dt_joined: 1 })
```

for more details check official site - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following.

```
db.student.find({}, {_id:1, dt_joined: 1 })

db.student.find({}, {name: 0 })
```